# showing list on text change event

Tags: popup

I am using VS 10 and SQL Server 2008. I want to show popup-list on text box change event, such that user can select from the list. This list will show 3 columns of particular table.

User should be able to select a particular item from the list and that selected record will be extracted in form fields.

How can I create such a pop-up list? and call it on text-change event?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Popup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.aspx) and [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.aspx).Set ListView as child of Popup control.3 columns can set as Listview sub items(3 subitems in a ListView Item).In text changed event your textbox, show pop-up control.